# What regulation or publication specifies that a TAF is good for a 5 statute mile radius around the reporting point?

Tags: faa-regulations, taf

It is [commonly](https://flightcrewguide.com/wiki/meteorology/terminal-aerodrome-forecast-taf/) [cited](http://www.askacfi.com/24740/metar-coverage-distance.htm) that a Terminal Aerodrome Forecast (TAF) is good for 5 statute miles around the airport it's forecasting for, but where is that 5 statute mile specification? I looked in the FAR/[AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap7_section_1.html) and the and I could only find information about decoding them and when they were updated.

What publication specifies that the TAF covers a 5 statute mile radius (in the US)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it in two official US government documents where it describes the 5 SM radius for TAFs.

One from NOAA:

> NWS TAFs consist of the expected meteorological conditions significant to aviation at an airport for a specified time period. For the U.S., **this is the area within five (5) statute miles (SM)** of the center of an airport’s runway complex.

Source: National Weather Service Instruction 10-813. November 18, 2020. Operations and Services. Aviation Weather Services, [NWSPD 10-8. Terminal Aerodrome Forecasts](https://www.nws.noaa.gov/directives/sym/pd01008013curr.pdf). p. 5.

And one from the FAA in [AC 00-45H - Aviation Weather Services - Change 2](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1030235) on page 5-84 *(emphasis added)*:

> **5.13 Terminal Aerodrome Forecast (TAF).**
>
> A TAF is a concise statement of the expected meteorological conditions significant to aviation for a specified time period *within 5 sm of the center of the airport’s runway complex (terminal).* The TAFs use the same weather codes found in METAR weather reports (see paragraph 3.1) and can be viewed on https://www.aviationweather.gov.

Comment: That is consistent with the definition of "vicinity" at ICAO level, in [Annex 3](https://www.icao.int/airnavigation/IMP/Documents/Annex%203%20-%2075.pdf), §4.4.2.7: "*Vicinity— Between approximately 8 and 16 km of the aerodrome reference point and used only in METAR and SPECI with present weather in accordance with the template shown in Table A3-2*". I guess 8 km comes from the conversion of 5 sm.

Comment: In the U.S., "vicinity" in the METAR or TAR is weather between 5 and 10 SM.

Comment: In weather reports (TAF and METAR) according to the AIM (https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM.pdf) the abbreviation VC means *Vicinity, but not at aerodrome. In the US METAR, 5 to 10 SM from the point of observation. In the US
TAF, 5 to 10 SM from the center of the runway complex. Elsewhere, within 8000m.* (Fig 7-1-22) However, my question was, "where is it specified that TAFs cover 5 SM?" Which I found in the answer above. It makes sense then, that you'd assume the weather reported in the TAF was within that 5 SM radius, and if not, the TAF uses the qualifier **VC**.